# Изменение значения поля в строке таблицы через JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Прошу помочь советом, как написать очень небольшой скрипт на JS, который бы изменял значение поля "Дата создания детали" на целевое время (не реальное, а которое необходимо вручную указать в скрипте), но при этом делал бы это изменение не через table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML, а через указание номера детали.

Я в кодинге, в целом (и в JS, в частности) - полный ноль, поэтому примерно представляю работу скрипта так:

if ("тут пишется заданный номер детали вручную" = искомый номер детали)

Изменение даты с дефолтной на "тут пишется дата вручную"

else ("тут пишется заданный номер детали вручную" != искомый номер детали)

вывод ошибки "не найдено детали" обычным текстом, по аналогии с printLn от Java

При этом нет необходимости создавать диалоговые окна и иные средства представления, всё организовано через программный интерфейс, т.е. нужен ТОЛЬКО скрипт.
На HTML создан пример таблицы просто потому, что я не знаю, как по-другому представить данный пример. В реальной жизни это некая база данных, которая управляется через HP Service Manager, который, в свою очередь, вроде как имеет возможность писать скрипты для управления базой данных на чистом JS наподобие VBA-макросов в MS Excel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
    table, td{
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    table, th{
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    td{
        padding: 4px;
    }
    td input{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font: inherit;
        height: 28px;

    }
    td input:focus{
        outline: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .editable td{
        padding: 0;
    }
    #edit{
        width: 800px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<table id="Детали">
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Номер детали</th>
        <th>Дата создания детали</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="0">
        <td data-type="text">IM0123</td>
        <td data-type="number">01.01.1980 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td data-type="text">IM0234</td>
        <td data-type="number">01.01.1980 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td data-type="text">IM0345</td>
        <td data-type="number">01.01.1980 00:00</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('Детали');
    table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML = '21.11.2019 16:00'
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: А в чем прикол? Почему нельзя сразу в html вписать нужную дату?

Comment: В том то и загвоздка, что нужно использовать JS-скрипт.
Если бы была возможность, то конечно, через html я давно всё бы поменял

Comment: Спасибо Вам, добрый человек).
Напишите это как ответ, чтобы я Вас отметил галочкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var headings = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item__heading');

headings.forEach(changeDate);

function changeDate(heading) {
  var dateField = heading.nextElementSibling;

  switch (heading.innerText) {
    case 'IM0123':
      dateField.innerText = '18.06.2015 10:00';
      break;
    case 'IM0234':
      dateField.innerText = '3.04.2013 11:20';
      break;
    case 'IM0345':
      dateField.innerText = '1.10.2019 12:20';
      break;
    default:
      dateField.innerText = '01.01.1980 00:00';
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <h2 class="list__item__heading">IM0123</h2>
    <div class="list__item__date">01.01.1980 00:00</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <h2 class="list__item__heading">IM0234</h2>
    <div class="list__item__date">01.01.1980 00:00</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <h2 class="list__item__heading">IM0345</h2>
    <div class="list__item__date">01.01.1980 00:00</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Кстати, а если есть уже дефолтное значение времени создания детали (например 01.01.1980 00:00) и необходимо изменить его? Например, <div class="list__item__date">01.01.1980 00:00</div> - как можно поменять значение через JS?

Comment: Не меняет, к сожалению. Хотя должно, по идее скрипту без разницы, пустое поле или чем-то заполнено

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Забыл добавить закрывающий тег </script>. Всё работает.
Ещё раз благодарю Вас.

Answer (score 2):

Ну раз таке дело... вместо того, чтобы менять один кусок таблицы в зависимости от другого куска, можно сразу всё заполнение привязать к массиву данных. Так и редактировать будет удобнее:

```js
let DETAILS = [
  {name: "IM0123", time: "01.01.1980 00:00", bubu: "15"},
  {name: "IM0234", time: "05.05.1980 00:00", bubu: "45"},
  {name: "IM0345", time: "09.09.1980 00:00", bubu: "105"},
];

/***************************/

fillTable('Детали');

function fillTable(id){
  let trs = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id + ' tbody tr');
  
  Array.from(trs).forEach(function(tr, index){
    let td = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
    
    let d = DETAILS[index];
    td[0].textContent = d.name;
    td[1].textContent = d.time;
    td[2].textContent = d.bubu;
  });
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td, th { padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; }
```

```html
<table id="Детали">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Номер детали</th>
      <th>Дата создания детали</th>
      <th>bubu</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-type="text"></td>
      <td data-type="number"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-type="text"></td>
      <td data-type="number"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-type="text"></td>
      <td data-type="number"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```